# How to consume messages from a Debezium topic from Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus, debezium

I'm trying to set up an application which produces change events with MySQL+Debezium+Kafka. I'd like to consume messages from the Debezium topic with a Quarkus Microprofile application.
I'm using the following configuration on the Quarkus side to capture incoming messages:

```
mp.messaging.incoming.customers.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.incoming.customers.topic=dbserver1.inventory.customers
mp.messaging.incoming.customers.value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

That works, however the change event, when captured with a StringDeserializer, does not just contain the changed record:

```
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"id"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"first_name"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"last_name"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"email"}],"optional":true,"name":"dbserver1.inventory.customers.Value","field":"before"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"id"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"first_name"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"last_name"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"email"}],"optional":true,"name":"dbserver1.inventory.customers.Value","field":"after"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"version"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"connector"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"name"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"ts_ms"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"name":"io.debezium.data.Enum","version":1,"parameters":{"allowed":"true,last,false"},"default":"false","field":"snapshot"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"db"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"table"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"server_id"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"gtid"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"file"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"pos"},{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"row"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"thread"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"query"}],"optional":false,"name":"io.debezium.connector.mysql.Source","field":"source"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"op"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"ts_ms"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"id"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"total_order"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"data_collection_order"}],"optional":true,"field":"transaction"}],"optional":false,"name":"dbserver1.inventory.customers.Envelope"},"payload":{"before":null,"after":{"id":1005,"first_name":"myname","last_name":"myusername","email":"amail@mail.com"},"source":{"version":"1.3.0.Final","connector":"mysql","name":"dbserver1","ts_ms":1603634203000,"snapshot":"false","db":"inventory","table":"customers","server_id":223344,"gtid":null,"file":"mysql-bin.000003","pos":364,"row":0,"thread":6,"query":null},"op":"c","ts_ms":1603634203419,"transaction":null}}
```

How can I extract the changed data from this huge JSON?
which in my case is:

```
{"id":1005,"first_name":"myname","last_name":"myusername","email":"amail@mail.com"}
```

Should I keep using a StringDeserializer and use JSONB and iterate through the JSON Payload? or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a better approach for that, however, as the text is a JSON, using a custom Deserializer that extends would JsonbDeserializer work:

```
@RegisterForReflection
public class CustomerDeserializer extends JsonbDeserializer<Customer> {

    @Override
    public Customer deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(new String(data)));
        JsonObject jsonObject = reader.readObject();

        JsonObject payload = jsonObject.getJsonObject("payload");
        String firstName = payload.getJsonObject("after").getString("first_name");
        String lastName = payload.getJsonObject("after").getString("last_name");
        String email = payload.getJsonObject("after").getString("email");
        return new Customer(firstName,lastName,email);

    }
}
```

Edit: You can find the full [Debezium example](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/debezium/how-to-capture-data-changes-with-debezium) here.

Comment: @this is not working